# Redis on Heroku Sharding

Tags: heroku, redis, redistogo

I'm evaluating possibility of using heroku plus RedisToGo addon.

I've read that there is a possibility to set up standalone redis cluster with sharding and replication.

However in [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo#using_redis_from_java) I see examples of `JedisPool` usage instead of `ShardedJedisPool`.

Does it mean that redis on heroku does not scale and shard?
Or is it done internally?

Comment: Where did you "read that there is a possibility to set up standalone redis cluster with sharding and replication."?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [Redis To Go Add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/redistogo) does not support sharding or replication in any of its plans.

However, it's often the case that add-on providers will work with you to support custom requirements if you contact them directly. You can expect the cost of such plans to increase appropriately.